# CouchDB _session not returning cookie

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, couchdb, session-cookies, progressive-web-apps

**Environment:**

- CouchDB 2.2.0 running on VirtualBox, running up-to-date Debian image.  Network type is bridged, all ports are open, no https.
- Vue3.js app (not using any Vue functionality to access the DB)
- Remote access JS package:

  - axios
  - fetch

Browser: Chrome latest

**Relevant CouchDB local.ini settings**

```
[couch_peruser]
enable = false
delete_dbs = false

[chttpd]
port = 5984
require_valid_user = false
proxy_use_secret = false
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
authentication_handlers = {chttpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}

[httpd]
bind_address = 127.0.0.1
enable_cors = true

(default authentication handlers set in default.ini)
authentication_handlers = {couch_httpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {couch_httpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}

[couch_httpd_auth]
secret = (hash num)
require_valid_user = false
allow_persistent_cookies = true


[cors]
origins = *
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName, origin, referer
credentials = true
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
```

**What Happens**

If I do the query via curl, I get a cookie in the response.

Here's the curl call:

```
curl -v http://couchman.lcldev:5984/_session \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H "X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName:<uname>" \
  -d '{"name":"<uname>","password":"<passwd>"}'
```

And here's the response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
< Content-Length: 47
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 21:16:10 GMT
< Server: CouchDB/2.2.0 (Erlang OTP/19)
< Set-Cookie: (cookie info)
<
{"ok":true,"name":"<name>","roles":["<roles>"]}
```

Yay.  I get a cookie.

But if I call it from within my app (with either *fetch* or *axios*), I only get these headers:

```
Response headers: 
  cache-control,must-revalidate
  content-type,application/json
  server,CouchDB/2.2.0 (Erlang OTP/19)
```

No *Set-Cookie* header.

So, what's up?  What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure that in your frontend JavaScript code, you’re setting 'withCredentials: true' or 'credentials:"include"' for the request.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.

So, in 'fetch', I set 'credentials':"include" and it did indeed set a cookie in the browser that I could see in the 'application' debug output.

However, I don't see the header.  Does the browser absorb it?

The next question is how do I get to it so I can pass it to CB on subsequent requests?  I didn't get a header, and 'document.cookie' doesn't show anything.

(Setting 'withCredentials: true' in axios did not yield a cookie, btw)

Comment: (the app is a PWA, btw.  I wouldn't think that would make a difference, but I wonder if cookies are handled differently in PWA's?  Have to research...)

Comment: Browsers will never let you access the Set-Cookie response header from frontend JavaScript code. Set-Cookie is defined as a “forbidden” response header name. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name. “Forbidden” in this context means frontend code is forbidden from accessing any response header with that name. Set-Cookie is intended for use only by the browser itself.

Comment: gotcha.  So, I (think) I still have to get it to present it to CB for subsequent queries.  Researching, it seems google.chrome has implemented an entirely new mechanism for accessing cookies and it may be related to the PWA/ServiceWorker imp.  Have to study more...

Comment: Uh, of course: the browser presents the cookie for subsequent queries.  Still have questions though.  Have to present in other issues.  Call this one answered.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in first comment - see thread for more info.